# Want users to be allowed to Download PDFs without other permissions

Tags: permissions, pdf, download, quick-links

We're using the "quick links" webpart in a modern SharePoint site on 365. The quick links are pointing to documents in a document library.

Unfortunately, the "Quick Links" appends "?web=1" to all in-site document links and forces it to open using SharePoint's viewer. We haven't found a way around that.

However, an alternative might be to allow SharePoint's viewer to allow "Download" for these users. They are in a group that has applied permission level "Read without System Pages" which is just a copy of the "Read" permission set but without "Create Alerts" and "View Application Pages".

Users with this permission level can not see the "Download" button when viewing PDF files with the SharePoint viewer. The "Read" permission level is specifically described as "Can view pages and list items and **download** documents."

So, why can't they see the "Download" button? It is always something with SharePoint... isn't it?

Comment: Searches regarding this always lead to the opposite - people who want to *restrict* downloads rather than allow them.

Comment: I think users will need "View Application Pages" permissions. Can you test once by allowing these permissions? When trying to download file, SharePoint uses `/_layouts/15/download.aspx` application page in SharePoint: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/11/10/sharepoint-online-download-files-using-json-formatting/

Comment: Looks like someone had broken inheritance on this library and set users to "View Only". Once we fix that, I will test the change and see if that resolves it. Strangely, the "View Only" permission *does have* "View Application Pages" enabled, but it still isn't working for them.

Comment: View only does not allow downloading files. You need Read permissions for downloading files.